# isNAN not evaluating

Tags: javascript, forms, events

Newb here trying to learn

I'm attempting to check the data entered into my form, if the data entered into the second or third inputs is not numeric (i.e. is alphabetical) display notice to user that info is not numeric. I am using the 'isNaN' function to do this, but it's not working as I'd hoped based on what i've read on Google, Stack and other places. I've tried both 'isNaN' and '!isNaN', neither one triggers the hoped for event within my script.

Here is the JavaScript i am attempting:
    if(empty(thisForm.epiName,"Episode name left blank. Please enter the name of episode submitting so we can boldly go and check your results!")){return false;}

```
        if(empty(thisForm.rsTot,"Red shirt total left blank. Please enter the total estimated number of Starfleet officers wearing red shirts to appear in this episode so we can boldly go and check your results!")){return false;}

        if(empty(thisForm.reRemaining,"Red shirts surviving left blank. Please enter the number of Starfleet officers to survive this episode so we can boldly go and check your results!")){return false;}

        if(isNaN(thisForm.rsTot,"Info entered is not a number, we can not boldly check your result!")){return false;}

        if(isNaN(thisForm.reRemainder,"Info entered is not a number, we can not boldly check your result!")){return false;}



        return true;//if all is passed, submit!
```

Site url: http://zephir.seattlecentral.edu/~jstein11/itc250/z14/_sbx031_OOPform/sbx031b_OOPform.php

Comment: I've set up a codeshare here of the files complete code: http://codeshare.io/8qzYO For those who've not tried it, CodeShrare is pretty cool as it allows you to share live code in an editor and you can select how it displays (as html, javascript, php, et al) and you'll see code highlighting and line numbers.

Comment: Why are there two parameters in `isNaN`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Furthermore, what does `empty` do (that is not a standard JavaScript function)?

Comment: If 'empty' the form input returns 'false' and the message displays as an alert.  See the link for the form - if you leave an input empty you get the empty message.

Comment: OK. I see that in the `util.js` function. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Why are you passing second values to isNaN? and why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: `isNaN()` is used to detect `NaN` values only, it's not purposed to check, if its argument is a number. Also despite of you've an alert in `empty()` showing the passed string, the native `isNaN` doesn't have that kind of method.

Comment: @rlemon - if you look at the codeshare link you will see that the page is php in nature, but i think the error is from/in the javascript (hopefully?). The second value is the message that displays if the data is non a number - if i'm understanding what you mean by 'second value'

Comment: Thank you for that information @teemu, I'm trying new things and stumbling along. Maybe i have to go back to my drawing board and have a new think.

Comment: @Alex Morrise nope not getting any errors in my console.

Comment: @Teemu - thank you very helpful guidance. I thought that i could replace the 'empty' with 'isnan' to process the same way which now i see is not the case. I've got lots of re-reading to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isNaN accepts only 1 argument.
Also, you should be aware that the argument is coerced into a Number before being checked.

To avoid unexpected results, it's best to check if it's a Number first.

```
function safeIsNaN(num) {
    if (typeof num !== "number") {
        return true; //this is Not-a-Number
    }  
    return isNaN(num);
}
```

Comment: `typeof NaN === 'number';`

Comment: And at the same time: `isNaN(NaN) -> true` so this function would still work. (EDIT): You can pass a string into isNaN and it will still properly test it. In fact, you can pass any value into isNaN and it will not throw an error.

Comment: @rlemon yes, but `isNaN(NaN) === true`

Answer (score 2):

At first, for example `thisForm.rsTot` in your code is an HTMLElement, it can never be a number. A fix would be something like this:

```
if(isNaN(+(thisForm.rsTot.value))) {
    alert("Info entered is not a number, we can not boldly check your result!");
    return false;
}
```

Unary `+` will convert its operand to a number, if this fails, the operand is converted to `NaN`, which then is checked by `isNaN`. I've preferred unary + , since `parseFloat()` returns possible leading numbers from a string, unary + always gives `NaN`, if there's even one non-numeric character in the string.

Notice, that you have to use the value of the `input` instead of the element itself. This value is always a string.

---

A general way to check if a variable is a number:

```
function isNumber (n) {
    return (!isNaN(+n) && isFinite(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value of the form field into isNaN, plus as the comments mentioned, the isNaN function only takes one argument. You will need some other way of showing the error message to the user:

```
if (isNaN(thisForm.reTot.value)) {
    // call some function to show error message, which you will need to create
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for syntax errors. BTW if you wanna check for something that is not a number (isNaN) you don't need the negation "!".

Try this for reference [JavaScript isNaN() on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Comment: Thanks - i looked at w3schools, and stack and several other places but i haven't found anything that i can manage to understand yet. I'm a newb stumbling through at the moment.

Comment: reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Examples

Comment: Thank you for the refence to the developer site, i did look there, but it's all a big mess in my mind right now - it's a fun mess but it's still a mess at the moment. yeah learning!